# redirect some urls with out shorten link

Tags: php, api, hyperlink

I've written a program to auto shorten the link and it use api of my website
but i have to when i click on an shortened link ( like : goo.gle/~~~ ) this program dont use my service and redirect to link with out Reshorten link!
as you know the shortner link service changing the urls 
now i need to a program that if find a content like ( goo.gle ) in my value then Regardless of Reshorten service and use the api

```
elseif ($url == "http://goo.gle/")
{
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: $url");
}

else
{

            $orls = "http://losa.net/api.php?key=dc4c0b38b62b44f69467c33eaf7ce08b&uid=128&adtype=int&url=".$url."";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$orls);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            $content=curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: $content");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but I will answer to what I understood.

1. You can determine if the URL is using a shortening service by using a regex and seeing if the first part of the url is under a certain amount of characters, not sure how long the longest one is, but something like 5 or less characters.
2. If it is then try to get PHP to capture the header and find out where it is redirecting two or use an API such as [LongUrl](http://longurl.org/api).
3. Reshorten.

Or if you are saying you want to disregard your API if the URL is already shortened you can do:

1. Same as step one of previous, use a regex to see if the first part is less than 5 characters.
2. Try to expand
3. If you can expand redirect.